# Inserting Image With Inline HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Web APIs, so sorry if I am missing information.  I am trying to send an email from my web api with an image (not as an attachment), but I am having issues with the inline html.

Example (This is in the WebAPI Controller)

```
message Body = "<p>Here is an image</p>" + Model.Image;
```

Now this will not work, as it displays "System.Byte[]", so my alternative was to convert it with some inline html, such as...

```
message Body = "<p>Here is an image</p>" + "<img src=\"data:image/gif;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String{Model.Image)\" />;
```

This will return an empty  element.  What am I doing wrong?  If I were to guess, I am not using quotations correctly, but I cannot find anyone trying to insert an image the way I am.

Site note - If I see what is being sent from the mobile app for the image, I am getting a huge string of text that is always the same, regardless of whether it is a different image.  I thought I would use that like src="data:image/gif;base64,", but I just get a long string returned in the email.

Comment: I believe that the correct way to use quotations inside inline html is \", so that question is out of the way.

Comment: Use this link : https://www.regiebaquero.com/csharp-base64-encoding/

Comment: This would involve saving the image to a drive somewhere.  However, I was able to find out that most email clients do not support base64 images.  So <img src=\"data:image/gif;base64,9d5f...9e==\" /> would not work.  I'll need to find a different way to get the image to appear in the emails.

Answer (score 0):

You need to host your image somewhere else and use the full path. Example:

```
<img scr="https://static.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/test-html-online-670x335.jpg" />
```

Comment: But the image is already in the API model.  The image is being sent and stored to the DB in the same controller.  Also, I wouldn't be able to use the HTML you posted in the controller since the syntax wouldn't match up.  I would need to put that code within quotations, which is where I am having issues figuring out.  Would the quotations for the src be /" or '?

Answer (score 0):

Most email clients do not display base64 images.  My solution was to attach the image to the email by using the following code.

```
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Model.Image);
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "Image.png", "image/png"));
```

I did not need to convert from byte to base64, as this was done on the mobile app before being sent to the API, so I just referenced the value that was stored in the model.